# Proving subspaces are T-invariant

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space, and let $T \in L(V)$, the set of linear mappings. A subspace W ⊆ V is T-invariant if $T(x) \in W \forall x \in W$, that is, $T(W) \subseteq W.$ Prove that the subspaces $\{0\}, V , range(T)$ and $ker(T)$ are all T-invariant.

How do I start this problem?

Comment: Where are you having trouble applying the definition of $T$-invariance? What is $T(0)$? Is it in $\{0\}$? Is $T(v) \in V$? Etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is just applying the definition. Take $ker(T)$ for example. $\forall v\in ker(T)$, $T(v)=0$ by definition of kernel. Clearly $0\in ker(T)$, so $T(v)\subseteq ker(T)$, hence $ker(T)$ is T-invariant.

I can write more if requested...

For $\{0\}, u\in\{0\}$ means $u=0$. So $T(0)=0\subset\{0\}$.

For $range(T), u\in Range(T), \implies T(u)\in Range(T)$ so Range is T-invariant.

Comment: can you explain the meaning of t-invariant in simple meaning? I missed class and im not understand the meaning.

Comment: @Thehelp, you take the subspace, and verify that applying the linear transformation $T$ to all elements in that subspace produces an image that is a subset of the subspace.